# Key Value pair from an array with key Value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, underscore.js

I have an array like this:

```
var arrayTemp = [
{"0":["Z",59]},
{"1":["D",53]},
{"2":["6",26]},
{"3":["3",19]},
{"4":["Y",10]},
{"5":["H",7]},
{"6":["G",5]},
{"7":["2",5]}
];
```

I need an output similar to the below one,

```
var arrayTemp = [
{"Z":59},
{"D":53},
{"6":26},
{"3":19},
{"Y":10},
{"H":7},
{"G":5},
{"2":5}
];
```

How do I achieve this? I would like this to be achieved with the help of json, underscore or JavaScript.

Comment: For what it's worth, *underscore or javascript* is a tautology.

Comment: There is no JSON here, nor will it help.

Comment: Can you post [**your code**](http://whathaveyoutried.com) you are currently attempting to read through your array with and generate the new required array, so we can have a look and see why it is not working? In addition, adding a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsFiddle.net) (or similar) that demonstrates the issue can be very helpful too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you could iterate trough each element of the original array and create the required objects, returning them as new elements in a new array.

```
var newArray = arrayTemp.map(function(e, index) { 
    var x = {};
    x[e[index][0]] = e[index][1];

    return x;
})
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EMzAL/) - Using `Array.prototype.map()` to create the new array

---

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var newArray = arrayTemp.map(function(e) { 
    var index = Object.keys(e).shift(),
        innerElement = e[index],
        ret = {};

    ret[innerElement[0]] = innerElement[1];
    return ret;
})
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y56PR/) to test.

Answer (score 0):

With underscore:

```
var newArr = _.map(arrayTemp, function(item){
    for (var i in item){
       var o = {};
       o[item[i][0]] = item[i][1];
       return o;
    }
});
```

Although @François_Wahl's solution is the better one in my esteem using the native Array.prototype.map().